# (Android Studio) Certain positions when clicked in my GridView don't work in very particular circumstances

Tags: android-studio, gridview, position

Alright, I can't figure out this bug. It is very specific and I can't find anything to help me online. I'm making a game of Checkers in Android Studio with a `GridView` and `ImageAdapter`. My code is probably a mess to most people, but hopefully someone can read it and figure out my issue.

The issue is that my checker pieces will not move to certain locations on the board. The green dots in this image are the spots it refuses to move to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxfb1.jpg.

Everything in the `OnItemClickListener` is Checkers game logic and it redraws the board within by resetting the `ImageAdapter`.

EDIT: I was asked to reduce the code to where I believe the problem lies, but I'm not entirely sure where it does lie. The issue is when one of the pieces highlighted with its surroundings highlighted can't moved into a highlighted tile as pictured above in the image. I honestly believe it is an issue with it not grid not detecting what item has been tapped, though I can tap any other tile to deselect the selected piece. I'm going to snip the movement bit because that is where it likely lies, but I'll also keep all the rest of the code intact below it.

Here is moving the piece code, where it will not work when trying to move a piece in the selected green spots in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxfb1.jpg):

```
if (placement[position] == 2) //MOVEMENT OF PIECE
                {
                    if ((placement[position + 14] == 6 || placement[position + 14] == 10) && (placement[position + 7] == 3 || placement[position + 7] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position + 7] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    } else if ((placement[position + 18] == 6 || placement[position + 18] == 10) && (placement[position + 9] == 3 || placement[position + 9] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position + 9] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    } else if (placement[position - 14] == 10 && (placement[position - 7] == 3 || placement[position + 7] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position - 7] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    } else if (placement[position - 18] == 10 && (placement[position - 9] == 3 || placement[position - 9] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position - 9] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < placement.length; i++) {
                        if (placement[i] == 6) {
                            placement[position] = 4;
                            placement[i] = 0;
                            redTurn = false;
                            turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                        } else if (placement[i] == 10) {
                            placement[position] = 8;
                            placement[i] = 0;
                            redTurn = false;
                            turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                        }
                        if (placement[i] == 2) {
                            placement[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here's the code (Sorry in advance, it's likely bad):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int[] placement = {
                    1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3,
                    3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1,
                    1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3,
                    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
                    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                    4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1,
                    1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4,
                    4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1 };
    ImageView pic;
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    int redScore = 0;
    int whiteScore = 0;
    boolean redTurn = true;
    boolean ai = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final GridView board = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.board);
        board.setAdapter(adapter);

        final TextView turnTeller = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Turn);
        if(!ai)
            turnTeller.setText("Red's Turn");
        else
            turnTeller.setText("");

        board.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (redTurn) {
                    if (placement[position] != 2) //DESELECT PIECE
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < placement.length; i++) {
                            if (placement[i] == 2) {
                                placement[i] = 0;
                            } else if (placement[i] == 6) {
                                placement[i] = 4;
                            } else if (placement[i] == 10) {
                                placement[i] = 8;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (placement[position] == 4 || placement[position] == 8) //SELECT PIECE
                    {
                        if (placement[position] == 4) {
                            placement[position] = 6;
                        } else {
                            placement[position] = 10;
                        }


                        if (position != 8 && position != 24 && position != 40 && position != 56 && position != 63 && position != 47 && position != 31 && position != 15) {
                            if (placement[position - 7] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 7] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position - 9] == 0) {


     placement[position - 9] = 2;
                        }
                        if (placement[position - 7] == 3) {
                            if (placement[position - 14] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 14] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position - 9] == 3) {
                            if (placement[position - 18] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 18] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position] == 10) {
                            if (placement[position + 7] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 7] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position + 9] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 9] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position + 7] == 3) {
                                if (placement[position + 14] == 0) {
                                    placement[position + 14] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                            if (placement[position + 9] == 3) {
                                if (placement[position + 18] == 0) {
                                    placement[position + 18] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (position == 8 || position == 24 || position == 40 || position == 56 || position == 63) {
                        if (placement[position - 7] == 0) {
                            placement[position - 7] = 2;
                        }
                        if (placement[position - 7] == 3) {
                            if (placement[position - 14] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 14] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position] == 10) {
                            if (placement[position + 7] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 7] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position + 7] == 3) {
                                if (placement[position + 14] == 0) {
                                    placement[position + 14] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (placement[position - 9] == 0) {
                            placement[position - 9] = 2;
                        }
                        if (placement[position - 9] == 3) {
                            if (placement[position - 18] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 18] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position] == 10) {
                            if (placement[position + 9] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 9] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position + 9] == 3) {
                                if (placement[position + 18] == 0) {
                                    placement[position + 18] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (placement[position] == 2) //MOVEMENT OF PIECE
                {
                    if ((placement[position + 14] == 6 || placement[position + 14] == 10) && (placement[position + 7] == 3 || placement[position + 7] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position + 7] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    } else if ((placement[position + 18] == 6 || placement[position + 18] == 10) && (placement[position + 9] == 3 || placement[position + 9] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position + 9] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    } else if (placement[position - 14] == 10 && (placement[position - 7] == 3 || placement[position + 7] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position - 7] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    } else if (placement[position - 18] == 10 && (placement[position - 9] == 3 || placement[position - 9] == 7) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position - 9] = 0;
                        redScore++;
                        redTurn = false;
                        turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < placement.length; i++) {
                        if (placement[i] == 6) {
                            placement[position] = 4;
                            placement[i] = 0;
                            redTurn = false;
                            turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                        } else if (placement[i] == 10) {
                            placement[position] = 8;
                            placement[i] = 0;
                            redTurn = false;
                            turnTeller.setText("White's Turn");
                        }
                        if (placement[i] == 2) {
                            placement[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (placement[1] == 4) //KING RED
                {
                    placement[1] = 8;
                } else if (placement[3] == 4) {
                    placement[3] = 8;
                } else if (placement[5] == 4) {
                    placement[5] = 8;
                } else if (placement[7] == 4) {
                    placement[7] = 8;
                }
                board.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            else if(ai == false)
            {
                if (placement[position] != 2) //DESELECT PIECE
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < placement.length; i++) {
                        if (placement[i] == 2) {
                            placement[i] = 0;
                        } else if (placement[i] == 5) {
                            placement[i] = 3;
                        } else if (placement[i] == 9) {
                            placement[i] = 7;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (placement[position] == 3 || placement[position] == 7) //SELECT PIECE
                {
                    if (placement[position] == 3) {
                        placement[position] = 5;
                    } else {
                        placement[position] = 9;
                    }


                    if (position != 8 && position != 24 && position != 40 && position != 56 && position != 63 && position != 47 && position != 31 && position != 15) {
                        if (placement[position + 7] == 0) {
                            placement[position + 7] = 2;
                        }
                        if (placement[position + 9] == 0) {
                            placement[position + 9] = 2;
                        }
                        if (placement[position + 7] == 4) {
                            if (placement[position + 14] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 14] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position + 9] == 4) {
                            if (placement[position + 18] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 18] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position] == 9) {
                            if (placement[position - 7] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 7] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position - 9] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 9] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position - 7] == 4) {
                                if (placement[position - 14] == 0) {
                                    placement[position - 14] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                            if (placement[position - 9] == 4) {
                                if (placement[position - 18] == 0) {
                                    placement[position - 18] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (position == 8 || position == 24 || position == 40 || position == 56 || position == 63) {
                        if (placement[position + 7] == 0) {
                            placement[position + 7] = 2;
                        }
                        if (placement[position + 7] == 4) {
                            if (placement[position + 14] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 14] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position] == 9) {
                            if (placement[position - 7] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 7] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position - 7] == 4) {
                                if (placement[position - 14] == 0) {
                                    placement[position - 14] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (placement[position + 9] == 0) {
                            placement[position + 9] = 2;
                        }
                        if (placement[position + 9] == 4) {
                            if (placement[position + 18] == 0) {
                                placement[position + 18] = 2;
                            }
                        }
                        if (placement[position] == 9) {
                            if (placement[position - 9] == 0) {
                                placement[position - 9] = 2;
                            }
                            if (placement[position - 9] == 4) {
                                if (placement[position - 18] == 0) {
                                    placement[position - 18] = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (placement[position] == 2) //MOVEMENT OF PIECE
                {
                    if ((placement[position - 14] == 5 || placement[position - 14] == 9) && (placement[position - 7] == 4 || placement[position - 7] == 8)&& placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position - 7] = 0;
                        whiteScore++;
                        redTurn = true;
                        turnTeller.setText("Red's Turn");
                    } else if ((placement[position - 18] == 5 || placement[position - 18] == 9) && (placement[position - 9] == 4 || placement[position - 7] == 8)&& placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position - 9] = 0;
                        whiteScore++;
                        redTurn = true;
                        turnTeller.setText("Red's Turn");
                    } else if (placement[position + 14] == 9 && (placement[position + 7] == 4  || placement[position + 7] == 8)&& placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position + 7] = 0;
                        whiteScore++;
                        redTurn = true;
                        turnTeller.setText("Red's Turn");
                    } else if (placement[position + 18] == 9 && (placement[position + 9] == 4 || placement[position + 9] == 8) && placement[position] == 2) {
                        placement[position + 9] = 0;
                        whiteScore++;
                        redTurn = true;
                        turnTeller.setText("Red's Turn");
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < placement.length; i++) {
                        if (placement[i] == 5) {
                            placement[position] = 3;
                            placement[i] = 0;
                            redTurn = true;
                            turnTeller.setText("Red's Turn");
                        } else if (placement[i] == 9) {
                            placement[position] = 7;
                            placement[i] = 0;
                            redTurn = true;
                            turnTeller.setText("Red's Turn");
                        }
                        if (placement[i] == 2) {
                            placement[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (placement[1] == 56) //KING RED
                {
                    placement[1] = 7;
                } else if (placement[3] == 58) {
                    placement[3] = 7;
                } else if (placement[5] == 60) {
                    placement[5] = 7;
                } else if (placement[7] == 62) {
                    placement[7] = 7;
                }
                board.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            if(!redTurn && ai)
            {

            }
        }
    });

}



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    int[] tiles = {R.drawable.blacktile, R.drawable.redtile, R.drawable.yellowtile,
                   R.drawable.whitepiece, R.drawable.redpiece, R.drawable.whitepieceselected, R.drawable.redpieceselected,
                   R.drawable.whiteking, R.drawable.redking, R.drawable.whitekingselected, R.drawable.redkingselected};
    public ImageAdapter (Context c) {context=c;}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return placement.length;}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return tiles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        pic = new ImageView(context);

        pic.setImageResource(tiles[placement[position]]);

            pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            pic.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(51,51));

            return pic;
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mcollins499.mcollins_prog11.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Turn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Red's Turn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/board" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:contextClickable="false"
        android:numColumns="8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Turn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For reference on what the values in placement stand for:

```
0 = black tile  
1 = red tile  
2 = highlighted tile  
3 = black/white piece  
4 = red piece  
5 = highlighted black/white piece  
6 = highlighted red piece  
7 = black/white king  
8 = red king  
9 = highlighted black/white king  
10 = highlighted red king
```

Comment: Hi Miro!  Could you please reduce your question to a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I added a snippet of code where the issue likely lies, though I'm not 100% sure if it is that part or not. That is one of the issues I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

/u/anomie-p on reddit:

I haven’t really done much android dev but can’t you hook up a debugger and set a breakpoint and step it?

Also, you may want to make the game logic it’s own thing that can represent the game and take game actions independently of even having a UI and then hook the UI up into calling things on that. That would let you do things like spin up just a game representation and unit test it. It will also let you flip which side is the AI easier when you want that. Right now you've got things like whose turn it is tracked by UI code.

You’ve got a lot of repeating yourself in there too. I mean, I think you know you need cleanup so maybe I should stop talking. ;)

I’ve got some light stuff to start for work this morning but maybe after that I’ll pull down android stuff and bang on it a little - but you should definitely get it running with a debugger and breakpoint things and just trace out where it’s going wrong.

~~Can you kick me the xml / whatever needed for your drawables somehow? It would be easy and convenient for me - I’ve got the stuff loaded in android studio and I suppose I can just create the missing drawable definitions but just having what you’ve already got seems simpler/less error prone.~~

I just made some that seem to work well enough.

The problem: You are calculating indexes that are outside the position array, and trying to access them. So the runtime is throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and the app is crashing.

Expressions like:
(placement[position - 18] == 5 || placement[position - 18] == 9) && (placement[position - 9] == 4 || placement[position - 7] == 8)&& placement[position] == 2

will give you an index for any position that's < 18 or greater than (placement.length - 19), for instance.

My recommendation is still to rewrite things organized differently so that your game logic is not so tied to the UI - but if you want to continue this way, do something like

```
private boolean isPlaceEqual(int position, int offset, int value)
{
    int index = position + offset;
    if(index > -1 && index < placement.length)
    {
        return placement[index] == value;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and change your conditions to something like 
`else if(isPlaceEqual(position, -18, 5) || isPlaceEqual(position, 18, 9) ...`

(and use that safe bounds checking predicate anywhere you check the placement array for a value, for consistency - if there's no offset just pass it zero)